# Use a variable I made in a .php document within a separate .js document

Tags: php, javascript, variables

I've looked, and will continue to look through many more forum posts, but I have not found a solution to this simple question.

Easy enough, I get some data from a server, I manipulate this data in my .php file and create four variables. My variables are (for simplicity) $v1, $v2, $v3, $v4. Now I also have a .js file that I would like to use these four variables in. Specifically, I would like to use these variables in a google maps marker (but you don't have to answer if you do not know) but how might I grab these variables and use their values in my google maps marker (.js file)?

Comment: also have you looked at json encode and using ajax to pull the results from that?

Answer (score 1):

if you declare a global variable in a script tag prior to the external script being loaded will be available in the external script.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var v1 = <?=$v1?>,
        v2 = <?=$v2?>,
        v3 = <?=$v3?>,
        v4 = <?=$v4?>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/someExternalScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Some body
</body>
</html>
```

If you want, you could also define the variables in another page that you include like a javascript external file using the script tag. In the order the scripts appear in the source, later scripts will have access to global variables (global here means not defined within a function/closure scope) from previous scripts. For example, most people include jquery as an external script and all scripts included after jquery have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things:

1. Approach the problem properly.
2. Half-ass it.

I will give the second instruction first because it should give you some undestanding of how these two technologies are related.

## Half ass it

This assumes that the script you are writing is not Ajax-based - just some standard generate-page-with-PHP and include .js.

1. Write a php file that will generate Javascript content:

   ```
   // /js/vars.php
   $v1 = $v2 = $v3 = $v4 = time();

   header("Content-type: text/javascript");

   echo "window.Variables = {
       v1: $v1,
       v2: $v2,
       v3: $v3,
       v4: $v4
   }";
   ```

   (note that if the variables are strings, you should add quotes)
2. Require that file in `<head>` before the file you want to use the variables in.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript src="/js/vars.php">
   ```
3. Use it in your .js file.

   ```
   var smth = Variables.v1 + Variables.v2;
   ```

How this is a no-no for many reasons, amongst them:

- JavaScript generated by a PHP file is not easily maintainable.
- The global JS namespace is somewhat messy.
- It does not play well with Ajax.

## Proper

1. Write a php file that will generate JSON data:

   ```
   // /js/vars.php
   $v1 = $v2 = $v3 = $v4 = time();

   $jsonArr = array(
   'v1'=> $v1,
   'v2'=> $v2,
   'v3'=> $v3,
   'v4'=> $v4
   );
   header("Content-type: application/json");            
   echo json_encode($jsonArr);
   ```
2. Write some JavaScript code that will pull the data using Ajax. Eg. using jQuery:

   ```
   $.getJSON('js/vars.php', function(data) {
       alert(data.v1+data.v2);
   });
   ```